# How can I store the date from datepicker?

Tags: reactjs, date, datepicker

```
import React from 'react';
import { useState } from 'react';
import DatePicker from 'react-datepicker';
import 'react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css';

import './Card.css';

const Card = (props) => {
    const [selectedDate, setSelectedDate] = useState()
    return (
        <div className='tc bg-light-green dib br3 pa3 ma2 bw2 shadow-5'>
            <img alt ='grass' src={props.img}/>
            <div>
                <h1>Tuns la data de:</h1>
                <DatePicker 
                selected={selectedDate} 
                onChange={date => setSelectedDate(date)}
                dateFormat='dd/MM/yyyy'
                maxDate = {new Date()}
                />
                <h1>Data tundere:</h1>
                <h2>{props.name}</h2>
                <p>{props.speed}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Card;
```

Hello! This is my Card component and I want everytime when I run npm start, my [date picker value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cP2KY.jpg) to show last date i've picked up.
I`m thinking about use a var where I can store that value but I dont know where to put that variable.
Please, help me with that.

Comment: pass default date value from parent component in your card component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your React app and its components will not persist between runs of `npm start`. If you want to persist this value, you will need to save it to the browser's local storage, a local file, or to a database that is persisted.

Here's a quick tutorial for persisting in local storage: https://dev.to/selbekk/persisting-your-react-state-in-9-lines-of-code-9go